# How can I insert rows based previous and next record data into MS Access time sequenced data?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In MS Access , My Table is like this :

```
ProductName , Date , Time , Price
Apple , 05-April-2020, 9:15:59 , 110
Apple , 05-April-2020, 9:16:59 , 112
Apple , 05-April-2020, 9:17:59 , 108
Apple , 05-April-2020, 9:18:59 , 125
Apple , 05-April-2020, 9:20:59 , 110

Apple , 06-April-2020, 10:20:59 , 85
Apple , 06-April-2020, 10:21:59 , 82
Apple , 06-April-2020, 10:22:59 , 86
Apple , 06-April-2020, 10:25:59 , 84

Orange , 05-April-2020, 2:15:59 PM , 110
Orange , 05-April-2020, 2:16:59 PM , 112
Orange , 05-April-2020, 2:17:59 PM , 108
Orange , 05-April-2020, 2:18:59 PM , 125
Orange , 05-April-2020, 2:20:59 PM , 110

Orange , 10-April-2020, 2:21:59 , 85
Orange , 10-April-2020, 2:22:59 , 82
Orange , 10-April-2020, 2:26:59 , 86
Orange , 10-April-2020, 2:27:59 , 84
```

The data is from 9:15:59 AM to 3:29:59 PM for each date (always 59th second) for each product (thousands) for 4 years data.
I need to fill up the gaps for each product for every date , eg

```
9:19 AM for apple on 05 April-2020
10:23 AM for apple on 05 April-2020
10:24 AM for apple on 05 April-2020
```

so on.
Insert new records wherever needed copying the previous record price , coresponding productName and date , and new time.
If it can be (9:15 + 9:17 price)/2 , for 9:16 even better. Only wherever its missing.
Each Day for a specific product , if it has existence on that day, should have 375 rows coresponding to the 375 minutes from 9:15 to 3:30.
Ideally there should be no more than 5-10 inserts required per product per day. 
If we can generate a report , we can track how many inserts were made to track any false entries.

Thanks a lot , Looking forward :)

Comment: I think this will take close to forever in MS Access. I would recommend upgrading your database if you are storing millions of records over time.

Comment: It would be a one time exercise. 
Hence can wait for a few hours and let it run.
It might be inefficient , but my current knowledge limitation and setup to analyze the results is based on Access setup only. I am using vbCript to fetch rows and calculate prices etc. Right now would like to work on this and later change setup as i learn other tools. Using Access as its the easiest.

Comment: can you suggest a simple free database tool and coding platform.
What would be the pair for a beginner - database + code.
My purpose is such :
Fetch Apple+Orange buy price at 9:30 in the morning. if the TotalPrice drops below threshold exit loop , else continue till 3:15. Output the date wise results into Excel Sheet. Variations in this. There can be more than 2 products. We may sell apple at 12 and orange at 3:15 etc if apple is in loss but not orange. Its StockMarket data with analogy of FruitNames.

Answer (score 1):

I've put together some code that generates the missing records, including carrying over the last value from the previous day if needed.

However, I'm making absolutely no guarantees about the speed!!

```
Sub sMissingPrice()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsDay As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsLookup As DAO.Recordset
    Dim dtmTemp As Date
    Dim strSQL As String
    Const JetDateFmt = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#;;;\N\u\l\l"
    Const JetTimeFmt = "\#hh\:nn\:ss\#;;;\N\u\l\l"
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Set rsDay = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT ProductName, ProductDate FROM tblProductPrice ORDER BY ProductName, ProductDate;")
    If Not (rsDay.BOF And rsDay.EOF) Then
        Do
            dtmTemp = #9:15:59 AM#
'   make sure that there is a value for 09:15:59. otherwise get the last price from the previous day
            strSQL = "SELECT ProductTime, Price FROM tblProductPrice " _
                & " WHERE ProductName='" & rsDay!ProductName & "' AND ProductDate=" & Format(rsDay!ProductDate, JetDateFmt) & " AND ProductTime=" & Format(dtmTemp, JetTimeFmt)
            Set rsLookup = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
            If (rsLookup.BOF And rsLookup.EOF) Then
                Set rsLookup = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Price FROM tblProductPrice " _
                    & " WHERE ProductName='" & rsDay!ProductName & "' AND ProductDate=" & Format(rsDay!ProductDate - 1, JetDateFmt) & " AND ProductTime=" & Format(#3:29:59 PM#, JetTimeFmt))
                If Not (rsLookup.BOF And rsLookup.EOF) Then
                    db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblProductPrice (ProductName,ProductDate,ProductTime,Price) " _
                        & " SELECT '" & rsDay!ProductName & "'," & Format(rsDay!ProductDate, JetDateFmt) & "," & Format(dtmTemp, JetTimeFmt) & "," & rsLookup!Price
                End If
            End If
' now loop through each minute of the day checking to see if we have data
            Do
                strSQL = "SELECT Price FROM tblProductPrice " _
                    & " WHERE ProductName='" & rsDay!ProductName & "' AND ProductDate=" & Format(rsDay!ProductDate, JetDateFmt) & " AND ProductTime=" & Format(dtmTemp, JetTimeFmt)
                Set rsLookup = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
                If (rsLookup.BOF And rsLookup.EOF) Then
                    Set rsLookup = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Price FROM tblProductPrice " _
                        & " WHERE ProductName='" & rsDay!ProductName & "' AND ProductDate=" & Format(rsDay!ProductDate, JetDateFmt) & " AND ProductTime=" & Format(DateAdd("n", -1, dtmTemp), JetTimeFmt))
                    If Not (rsLookup.BOF And rsLookup.EOF) Then
                        db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblProductPrice (ProductName, ProductDate, ProductTime, Price) " _
                            & " SELECT '" & rsDay!ProductName & "'," & Format(rsDay!ProductDate, JetDateFmt) & "," & Format(dtmTemp, JetTimeFmt) & "," & rsLookup!Price
                    End If
                End If
                dtmTemp = DateAdd("n", 1, dtmTemp)
            Loop Until dtmTemp > #3:30:00 PM#
            rsDay.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsDay.EOF
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsDay.Close
    rsLookup.Close
    Set rsDay = Nothing
    Set rsLookup = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sMissingPrice", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: thanks a lot. I am trying now. In Access Created a new module and pasted your code. Matched it with exact table,field names. Getting Error 3021 , No current record. speed is not a problem as this would be a one time exercise. accdb file Uploaded here :   [link] https://wetransfer.com/downloads/803fcb4c8feeeaebb36e59b6562055ac20200406041930/5f7b13 [/link]  , in case you wish to try running on large demo data.

Comment: At a guess, it is failing because for one item there is no price at the start of the first day, starting at 11:30 rather than 09:15. I'll modify the code to code around this.

Comment: yes , its running now.  yes indeed it is taking time. problem is we do not know what is happening the module just shows "running".
one optimization which we can maybe do is :
the product names are approx 5000 only across all dates. so we can save time with the "distinct" criteria and check from this list , which we can save in a new table called productNames. Do you think that can be done ? And how ? Will it help ?

Comment: You would also need to store the list of distinct days for each product as well. It could be made slightly faster by storing the price for the current time in a variable, which means that you won't need to open a recordset to get the previous minute's price. In addition, I assume that ProductName, ProductDate and ProductTime are all indexed as that will speed up the returning of data in recordsets.

Comment: can you help with an improved code please , the code is still running. we can also generate a csv file , if that is possible , and append all together at once later on. repeated inserts can be avoided. i can make a table called product name.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a free code writing service - I have given you enough code as a starting point. And with 2 billion+ records (5000 products x 365 days x 4 years x 375 time slots) this will be pushing the limits of MS Access.

Comment: sure , thanks a lot. it was very helpful. 
can you recommend me , as a beginner ,  the set of  software free and simple ,  i should start with as an alternative to access. i understand one database software like sql express and one coding like visual studio C# or python would be required. pls confirm. my purpose is to track prices like product1+product2+product3 together across the time Intraday per day. say if sum is > 100 then exit product3. else exit all together at 330pm. and tabulate the historical backtest results for analyzing the various permutations i try. thanks once again.

Comment: You may find that SQL Server Express is suitable. You would be able to write T-SQL to "fill in the blanks", and you would also be able to link the data to a MS Access front end.